# SPace between add to card button and calculator

Tags: wordpress, cart

[image]
Hi. I have this text that should be put in the middle of add to cart button and the calculator (after add to cart) but when I initialize in php my code:
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'cxc_after_add_to_cart_btn_content' );
function cxc_after_add_to_cart_btn_content(){
echo "Poți alege și varianta de plată în rate

";

}
the text is placing  after the calculator too. What should I do?

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'cxc_before_add_to_cart_btn_content' );
function cxc_before_add_to_cart_btn_content(){
echo "Poți alege și varianta de plată în rate

";

}